# Self referencing loop Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

I'm currently using WebApi 2.0 and EntityFrameWork and I'm having issues with it:

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'UserInfo' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.UserInfo_F7C6DF3909A804C5A9AC107297C8851F4CC9DF1CCA4A689B892B6C6EBA5A6EA8'. Path '[0].User'."

my DB is something like this: User-UserInfo and is 1-1 relationship, the PK of User is the PF in UserInfo;

```
public class User {    
        public int UserId { set; get; }
        public string username { set; get; }
        public string password { set; get; }
        public string name { set; get; }
        public string email { set; get; }
        public string surname { set; get; }
        public string lastName { set; get; }
        public int age { set; get; }
        public DateTime regDate { set; get; }
        public bool userType { set; get; }

        //we define our relationships
        //1-1 UserModel-UserInfo
        public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { set; get; }
}
```

My UserInfo class:

```
public class UserInfo { 
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { set; get; }        
    public string username { set; get; }        
    public string phone{ set; get; }        
    public string adress { set; get; }        
    public string country { set; get; }        
    public string city { set; get; }        
    public string zip { set; get; }

    //we define our relationships 
    //1-1 UserModel-UserInfo
    public virtual User User { set; get; }

}
```

In Postman I send a Post request and register a user:

```
{
  "username": "otmanlicona",
  "password": "pwd1234",
  "name": "Otman",
  "email": "otmanlicona17@mail.com",
  "surname": "licona",
  "lastName": "ledezma",
  "age": 33,
  "regDate": "2017-03-01T18:10:11+00:00",
  "userType": false
}
```

If I send a GET request I get all the users:

```
[
  {
    "Orders": [],
    "ReviewProducts": [],
    "UserInfo": null,
    "UserId": 7,
    "username": "otmanlicona",
    "password": "pwd1234",
    "name": "Otman",
    "email": "otmanlicona17@mail.com",
    "surname": "licona",
    "lastName": "ledezma",
    "age": 33,
    "regDate": "2017-03-01T12:10:11",
    "userType": false
  },
  {
    "Orders": [],
    "ReviewProducts": [],
    "UserInfo": null,
    "UserId": 8,
    "username": "angelsilva",
    "password": "pwd1234",
    "name": "angel",
    "email": "angelsilva@mail.com",
    "surname": "silva",
    "lastName": "borja",
    "age": 22,
    "regDate": "2017-03-01T12:10:11",
    "userType": true
  }
]
```

No problems so far , the problem is when I insert the UserInfo:

```
{
  "UserId": 8,
  "username": "angelsilva",
  "phone": "12345678",
  "adress": "550 Swallow Hill",
  "country": "USA",
  "city": "foo",
  "zip": "47-253"
}
```

If I send another GET request I get an Exception: 
[Image of the error](https://imgroll.net/i/DD5M1)

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'UserInfo'

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?,Thanks

```
[
  {
    "Orders": [],
    "ReviewProducts": [],
    "UserInfo": null,
    "UserId": 7,
    "username": "otmanlicona",
    "password": "pwd1234",
    "name": "Otman",
    "email": "otmanlicona17@mail.com",
    "surname": "licona",
    "lastName": "ledezma",
    "age": 33,
    "regDate": "2017-03-01T12:10:11",
    "userType": false
  },
  {
    "Orders": [],
    "ReviewProducts": [],
    "UserInfo": {
      "UserId": 8,
      "username": "angelsilva",
      "phone": "12345678",
      "adress": "550 Swallow Hill",
      "country": "USA",
      "city": "foo",
      "zip": "47-253"
    },
    "UserId": 8,
    "username": "angelsilva",
    "password": "pwd1234",
    "name": "angel",
    "email": "angelsilva@mail.com",
    "surname": "silva",
    "lastName": "borja",
    "age": 22,
    "regDate": "2017-03-01T12:10:11",
    "userType": true
  }
]
```

NOW I see what does Entity Framework meant by self referencing loop; What can I do so in my Get response only returns me the other values that aren't in the User Class like username,phone,address,country, etc.

Comment: Most likely nobody has any idea what you're doing wrong, you have not provided any code to that produces an exception.  [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Instead of adding the found solution to the question, accept Yashveer's answer.

Comment: Now that I found the solution , I came with another question, Do I have to ask another question or append it to this?

Comment: You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try this on startup .cs 

 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
= Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Comment: thanks I resolve the issue with: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; Which  is basically the same thing

Comment: @AngelSilva great

Comment: Though this solves your issue, consider using DTO's instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(); 

settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

 var Serializedata =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data,settings);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).