# Stop loading of self referencing entities in many to many

Tags: entity-framework, json.net

I have a many to many relationship in entity framework and its causing me serialisation problems as its looping infinity (using newtonsoft) I get the : Self referencing loop detected error:

I tried the options setting from [Self referencing loop Entity FrameWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562795/self-referencing-loop-entity-framework)

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
= Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

But it doesnt fix it. My classes look like:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

So in .net when I do a search on jobs can I tell it to only include tags and not jobs again after that? Ie with:

```
   // How to not include jobs in tags object?
   var jobs = context.Job.Include(x => x.Tags);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "don't send entities to the client, use a view model."

If all your client cares about is a Job and a list of it's tags:

```
[Serializable]
public class JobViewModel
{
    public int JobId { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public List<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; } = new List<TagViewModel>();
}
[Serializable]
public class TagViewModel
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then, selecting all jobs and their tags: (ideally this should have a Where clause or pagination, but for example's sake)

```
var jobs = context.Jobs.Select(j => new JobViewModel
{
    JobId = j.JobId,
    Title = j.Title,
    Tags = j.Tags.Select(t => new TagViewModel
    {
        TagId = t.TagId,
        Title = t.Title
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

You can avoid this manual casting using AutoMapper and it's `ProjectTo<T>` method which integrates nicely with EF's `IQueryable` based methods.

```
var jobs = context.Jobs
    .ProjectTo<JobViewModel>()
    .ToList();
```

Why?

- Avoid cyclic reference serialization issues.
- Optimize queries sent to the database to only pull back the fields needed.
- Reduce memory usage on the servers and client.
- Reduce the amount of data sent over the wire between servers, and to the client.
- Avoid sending more data to the client than is needed. (exposing entire domain model otherwise not shown)
- Avoid the risk of accepting entities back from the client, attaching, and saving changes that were not intended. (debugger manually altering fields or associated entities)